# Target Masking in Huggingface models

Tags: python, pytorch, bert-language-model, huggingface

I was implementing an encoder-decoder architecture, relying on a custom pytorch encoder and HuggingFace BERT as decoder (so I can't use the EncoderDecoder class of HuggingFace).

My task is translation, so I need to make BERT work in an autoregressive decoder. In the input I don't need word masking, only padding masking. However I do need to mask future target tokens not to "cheat" when training it.

I set the config parameters `is_decoder` and `use_cross_attention` to True, and by printing a summary looks like it is correctly linked with the encoder.
However, my issue raises because I don't know what I should pass to the forward method in order to correctly make the target mask.

According to the official documentation (https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/bert#transformers.BertModel), this is the declaration of the method:

```py
def forward(input_ids: typing.Optional[torch.Tensor] = None, 
    attention_mask: typing.Optional[torch.Tensor] = None, 
    token_type_ids: typing.Optional[torch.Tensor] = None, 
    position_ids: typing.Optional[torch.Tensor] = None, 
    head_mask: typing.Optional[torch.Tensor] = None, 
    inputs_embeds: typing.Optional[torch.Tensor] = None, 
    encoder_hidden_states: typing.Optional[torch.Tensor] = None, 
    encoder_attention_mask: typing.Optional[torch.Tensor] = None, 
    past_key_values: typing.Optional[typing.List[torch.FloatTensor]] = None, 
    use_cache: typing.Optional[bool] = None, 
    output_attentions: typing.Optional[bool] = None, 
    output_hidden_states: typing.Optional[bool] = None, 
    return_dict: typing.Optional[bool] = None ) → transformers.modeling_outputs.BaseModelOutputWithPoolingAndCrossAttentions or tuple(torch.FloatTensor)
```

According to the descriptions, both `attention_mask` and `encoder_attention_mask` are used to prevent attending over padding, so as source masks. I was wondering whether one of the two are instead used as target mask when BERT is in `is_decoder` mode, or if the target mask is automatically handled by HuggingFace, or if simply I'm trying something impossible.

By passing random values to one or the other or both it always gives me an output without exceptions, but I have no clue of what is happening internally, so no way to understand if that output is correct. To know it, I should first train the network, but my training will be very heavy, so I can't try al the possibilities but I need to understand what is happening.

I think that also a general example of BERT used as decoder, assuming to have a working custom encoder could be of great help

Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked into variants of the EncoderDecoder models though? It should still be possible to specify the respective models you want to use as both the Encoder and Decoder stack, with randomly initialized cross-attention values. AFAIK, there is no way that you could easily make BERT work in an autoregressive fashion.

Comment: Unfortunately the whole experiment has the aim of evaluating that custom encoder, when working with different and several types of decoder, including BERT. So I need to plug it and its weights to BERT. I now that BERT can be used as decoder because it is possible to define a bert2bert architecture in HuggingFace, so I was wondering how to make the same thing but with an encoder that is out of their repository.